# How to do a specific double "for" loop to do a calcul

Tags: c++

I would like to be able to do a loop that be able to make a count like this :

```
00  01  02  03  04
10  11  12  13  14
20  12  22  23  24
30  31  32  33  34
40  41  42  43  44
```

The way they are wrote is not important, I just want to be able do a count from 0 to 4 on the right number, then it do a + to the left number, and again 0 to 4

And here is what I've done

```
for (i; i <= TAILLE - 1; i++) {
    for (int i2=0; i2 <= TAILLE - 1; i2++) {
        //tableau[x][y] = false;
        cout << x << y << endl;
        y = i2;
    }
    x = i;
}
```

TAILLE = 5

x=0

y=0

i=0

i2=0

x is the left number
y the right number

Comment: 1) You've told what you've done, but you didn't ask a question to answer. 2) Why are you using `x` and `y` instead of `i` and `i2` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TAILLE; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j <TAILLE; j++) {
        cout << i << j << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

some notes on this code:

1.- Instead of `i<=TAILLE -1` use `i<TAILLE` it is shorter and easier to read. Also it is more computationally efficient since you avoid the subtraction, this is very subtle, but it's good to note this kind of detail, since in large datasets this could mean saving thousands or millions of calculations.

2.- Use `i, j, k` instead of `i, i2, i3`, this is not mandatory, but is kind of the standard and makes it easier to read as well.

3.- The variables `x` and `y` are not necessary, you can use directly `i` and `j`